# Getting Corrupted Data from Binary files after populating from keyboard

Tags: c, windows

I have written this piece of code below that testing a concept outside of my project before implementing.

after the `struct` variable has been populated from keyboard it is then written to a binary file and the process continues to get enough lines into the file as possible.

I then have another function that reads the data from the file and prints it to screen down to the last line, but when i print out the data i get corrupted data. all input is corrupted.

assistance please.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct ParkingInfo{
  int slot;
  char status[10];
  char clientCat[10];
  char owner[15];
}PARK;

PARK info;
int lengthBuffer_ = 250;

void populateFile();
void readFile();

int main(){
    populateFile();
    readFile();
}

void populateFile(){
    /*Variables*/
    FILE* fp = fopen("ParkingInfo.bin","wb+");
    PARK pk;

    if(fread(&pk,sizeof(PARK),1,fp)==0){//encounters EOF
        pk.slot=0;
        // will write to file {Slot# OPEN null null}
        for(int i=0;i<lengthBuffer_;i++){
            printf("Enter slot status: \n");
            fgets(pk.status,sizeof(pk.status),stdin);
            printf("Client category:\n");
            fgets(pk.clientCat,sizeof(pk.clientCat),stdin);
            printf("Owner Name: \n");
            fgets(pk.owner,sizeof(pk.owner),stdin);

            pk.slot++;
            fwrite(&pk,sizeof(PARK),1,fp);
        }
    }else{
        printf("FILE has content\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void readFile(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("ParkingInfo.bin","rb");
    PARK park;

    for(int i=0;i<lengthBuffer_;i++){
        fread(&park,sizeof(PARK),1,fp);
        printf("%i\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",park.slot,park.status,park.clientCat,park.owner);
    }
}
```

(EDIT):the ouput looks like:

```
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
4201152 α■a     a       ■   èj╨t}k╨t└@
```

EDIT:

After replacing the read method in `readFile` function with:

```
while(fread(&park,sizeof(PARK),1,fp)!=0){
        printf("%i\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",park.slot,park.status,park.clientCat,park.owner);
    }
```

it now prints nothing

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen` and `fgets`.

Comment: Exactly HOW is it corrupted...???  What did you enter via the keyboard, what did you get when re-reading...???  Details are important.

Comment: i entered my name for owner, closed for status and ultra premium for ClientCat

Comment: "ultra premium" is 14 bytes long (including null terminator)... ClientCat is only 10 bytes long.... this indicates one of the rules of programming... ALWAYS edit a user's input before using it... in this case it is too long.  Another suggestion is to provide a means of entering fewer than 250 entries during testing.  And in readFile(), you should take @coderredoc suggestion to check fread() return...

Comment: the reason i have not set a limit to how much time i can enter it because in my project, i have a function that auto populates the files with information that is then over written line by line when need by under conditions

Comment: You also should strip off the newline that fgets() puts in the buffer in most circumstances (be sure to read the man page).

Comment: interesting tidbit: on linux, the posted code works as expected.